# How do I replace array-style notation in templates with object-notation when switching from cakephp 2.x to 3.x

Tags: php, regex, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

When migrating, what is a fast way to replace the array notation of cakephp 2.x

```
echo $order['id'];
```

with the object notation of cakephp 3.x

```
echo $order->id;
```

in templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this regular expression works:
find this

```
\$order\['(\w+)'\]
```

and replace with this:

```
$order->\1
```

**Edit:** This above syntax works in the editor Sublime 2. In PHPStorm I needed to use this syntax for replacing:

```
\$offcut->$1
```

Comment: Keep in mind that some things that work as array keys won't work as object properties without using complex syntax. (For example: `$order['1example']`) I'm not sure if that applies in this scenario, but it may be something to look out for.

Comment: Also: you dont have to. The array notation continues to work just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I think You can use similar regex as above but "wider":

```
\['(.*?)'\](?1)?
```

And replace with:

```
->{'\1'}
```

This works recursive on contained fields in nested arrays, and it can handle potential syntax errors on numeric indexes by using curly braces.

Example in regexr: https://regexr.com/3k81v

Comment: for it to work I had to remove the curly braces and single ticks from the replace-expression.